# Remove a nested element from td and add it as the next row

Tags: jquery, each

Input:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="gvMasterGrid_ctl03_pnlWarning" class="warning">
        <span id="gvMasterGrid_ctl03_lblWarning">This has a problem</span>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Output:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <!--Moved to next row-->
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="gvMasterGrid_ctl03_pnlWarning" class="warning">
        <span id="gvMasterGrid_ctl03_lblWarning">This has a problem</span>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Using jquery. Selector should be css class and not element id

I am trying with

```
$(".warning").each(function(){
    $(this).closest("tr").after("<tr><td colspan = '999'>" + $(this).html() + "</td></tr>")
});
```

but it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

This will create a new row directly after the original one and move the content over for each element of the class `warning`. This assumes you only want a single `td` in the new row.

```
$(".warning").each(function () {
    // Get the parent row
    var parentRow = $(this).closest("tr");
    // Detach the content
    var content = $(this).detach();
    // Create a new row after the parent row
    var newRow = $('<tr><td></td></tr>').insertAfter(parentRow);
    // Get the cell and append the content
    newRow.children('td').append(content);
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ax8y5/)

Comment: @KashifKhan It does what I said it does, and I will prove it to you with [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/Ax8y5/1/). If that is not what you want it to do, then that is another matter entirely. If that is the case, please explain *why* it is not working.

Comment: Finally i got it. i just had to add it in document.ready. Thanks ruben. appreciate your effort

Comment: @KashifKhan Good to hear. Don't forget to upvote and/or accept an answer when it helps solve your issue.